# Gradle question: implementation vs runtimeClasspath, testImplementation vs testRuntimeClasspath

Tags: java, gradle

I'm new to Gradle.

The command:

```
$ ./gradlew dependencies
```

display a list of dependencies. would someone explain what is the differences between the followings?

```
implementation vs runtimeClasspath              // they both specifies dependencies for runtime
testImplementation vs testRuntimeClasspath      // they both specifies dependencies for testing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the gradle documentation [java_library_configurations_graph](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) provides the detailed explanation.
start point - *classpath are realised from the dependency configuration (impl...etc), you should not need to meddle with *classpath (unless doing something special)